Solve the hidden riddle
What is the hidden riddle, and what is the answer to the hidden riddle? The answer is one word.

Hi! I'm user5127!
How are you? Oh... What are you doing now?
Are you biking? Right, let's go to work and work. Eagles fly.
You seem nice to me. Outside, there is a bee. Uranus is a planet.
Well, the day is cold. Hot it is outside. Ants crawl. Tea is a drink.
Go on, tell me about your day! On your head, do you have hair?
Equations are expressions that equal each other. Silently, a snake crawls around your house.
Up, up and away the airplane goes! Puppies are dogs.
Bunnies are animals, like puppies. Understanding is the key to ace a test. Ten puppies and bunnies are dancing.
Not one, two. Even birds fly. Ventilation systems are important. Everything you see is not everything that is there. Run, run, you are almost at the end!
Go get first place! Oh, please tell me about your day!  Eggs are laid by some animals like chickens. So, how are you?
Download a file. Om nom nom, this taco is tasty! Win the race! Nod to what you agree with.

Extra credit: I keep trying to make you answer a question in that text. What is the question, and what is the answer? (This is unrelated to the question in the hidden riddle.)

Fixed it @bobble

The classic riddle hidden in this text can be found...

 ...by reading the first letters of each sentence (the content of the sentences is irrelevant). Together, these spell out (punctuation mine): HI, HOW ARE YOU? WHAT GOES UP BUT NEVER GOES DOWN?

The traditional answer to this is...

 ...your age.


Don't forget to answer the bonus question :P

@ConnieMnemonic Well, if you really want to know how I am, then the answer is still RELAXED!

Hah hah, excellent!

Good job! The bonus question is also correct.
